# Closed Javascript HTML5 replacing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

So im trying to make a table where it adds the content from 3 Textareas.

I succeeded in adding them but only with innerHTML but now im struggling to replace innerHTML with a DOM style(like appendChild etc.)

Table:

```
<header class="datagrid">
<h1> Zitatenbaum </h1>
<table id ="ZitatenOrdnung">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Zitat</th>
            <th>Autor</th>
            <th>Ihre Bewertung </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</header>
```

Form:

```
<form>
        <textarea  rows = "5" cols = "60" placeholder="Zitat einfügen" id = "Zitat1"> </textarea>
        <input type ="text" id="Autor1" placeholder="Autor einfügen"/>
        <input id="Bewertung" type="text" placeholder="Bewertung von 1-10" />
    <button id = "Einreichen">Einreichen </button>
     <button id = "Löschen">Löschen</button>
  </form>
```

Script:

```
<script>

    document.getElementById("Add").innerHTML = "Add";
    document.getElementById("Add").addEventListener("click",
        function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
                if((document.getElementById("Autor1").value !== "" && document.getElementById("Quote1").value !== ""&& (document.getElementById("Rating"
                    ).value > 1)  && document.getElementById("Rating").value < 10)){
                    var table = document.getElementById("ZitatenOrdnung");
                    var row = table.insertRow(1);
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                    cell1.lastChild.nodeValue = ('"' + document.getElementById("Quote1").value + '"');
                    cell1.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
                    cell2.innerHTML = ("~" + document.getElementById("Autor1").value);
                    cell3.innerHTML = (document.getElementById("Rating").value);
                    cell3.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
                    cell3.style.textAlign = 'center';
```

Answer (score 1):

The cells you've inserted are empty, they don't have childrens, so `lastChild` is undefined.

You may append a textNode instead:

```
cell1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('"' + document.getElementById("Zitat1").value + '"'));
```

There also isn't an element with the id `Quote1` (I guess you mean `Zitat1`)

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, i am german so i called it "Zitat1" but called it Quote1 so its english

Thanks for the help! it worked that way :D